Confusion regarding scope of different string declarations
I am confused regarding what can be done by a particular form of string declaration in C (e.g. pointer notation, array notation, malloced array). Mainly, I face a problem while changing the string or comparing two strings. I didn't get the exact logic behind why something is allowed for one declaration and not for other declaration. I briefly illustrate it here:
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
int main()
{
    char *str1 = "HelloWorld";
    char str2[] = "HelloWorld";
    char *str3 = (char *)malloc(11 * sizeof(char));
    str3 = "HelloWorld";
    printf("str1 = %s, str2 = %s, str3 = %s\n", str1, str2, str3);
    str1 = "Hello"; 
    //str2 = "Hello"; doesn't work .. instead we use strcpy(str2, "Hello");
    str3 = "Hello";
    printf("Enter new str2: ");
    scanf(" %s", str2);
    printf("str1 = %s, str2 = %s, str3 = %s\n", str1, str2, str3);
    return 0;
}


I am looking for explanations to these and if possible more such string operations, which often leads to Segmentation Fault or other errors. Also, I heard that generally it's preferred to use strcpy and strcmp instead of = and ==. Why is that so? And when do we need to be careful about it?

char *str3 = ...; followed by str = ...; makes you loose the original pointer. Use strcpy to copy a string, like strcpy(str3, "HelloWorld")

As for assignment to str2, it's an array and you can't assign to an array, only copy into its elements.

Maybe you'll like section 6 of the comp.lang.c FAQ ... and others :-)

str1 is not a string.  It is a pointer which is initialized to the address of the first element of a string literal.  str2 is not a string.  It is an array which is initialized from a string literal.  str3 is not a string.  It is a pointer which is assigned the value returned by malloc and then immediately re-assigned to the address of the first character of a string literal.

@WilliamPursell str2 is pretty much the text book definition of a C string. How is it not a string?

@Lundin  In C, a string is a null terminated array of char.  A char * is a variable that holds the address of a single char.  Often, we colloquially refer to the char * as a string, but it's not a string.  It is a pointer to a char.  If the char that it points to is the first character of a string, we do often refer to the pointer as a string; the point I am trying to make is that referring to it that way is only a colloquialism and is not technically accurate. Other than string literals, C really doesn't have strings at all.

@WilliamPursell Even though it is not a formal term, a nul terminated character array is referred to as a string/C string. Even the standard does this at some places, for example at 5.1.2.3.2 "...the array members argv[0] through argv[argc-1] inclusive shall contain pointers to strings...".


char *str1 = "HelloWorld";
The string literal (a form of array) "HelloWorld" is stored separately in a read-only section of the memory. A separately allocated pointer points at it.
str1 was incorrectly declared as char*, should always be const char* since the pointed-at memory cannot be modified.

char str2[] = "HelloWorld";
Here str2 is declared as an array and is pre-initialized with the contents of "HelloWorld". It gets size 11 which is the string length + 1 for nul termination.
str2 is read-write memory so it would be possible to change the contents. But not to change the size, since it is a statically sized array.

char *str3 = (char *)malloc(11 * sizeof(char));
This allocates 11 bytes dynamically on the heap, then allocates a pointer separately to point at that allocated chunk. This is read-write memory and can also be resized. However, dynamic allocation is slower than static allocation and comes with various risks such as memory leaks.
sizeof(char) is always 1 so that expression is redundant. The cast of the result is superfluous since malloc returns a void*. So this could be written simpler as char *str3 = malloc(11);.

str3 = "HelloWorld";
This is wrong - it reassigns the pointer from the allocated memory to instead point at a read-only string literal "HelloWorld like in the first str1 case. Since no pointer points at the part returned by malloc, this is now a memory leak bug. And attempting to free(str3) will cause a crash/seg fault etc.
Instead strcpy(str3, "HelloWorld") should have been used.

str1 = "Hello";
This reassigns the pointer to point at a different string literal, which is ok.

 //str2 = "Hello"; doesn't work .. instead we use strcpy(str2, "Hello");
Indeed, because str2 is an array, unlike the other two examples that are pointers. We can't assign directly to arrays in C simply because the language wasn't designed that way. strcpy is the correct solution indeed.

str3 = "Hello";
Same problem as before, this shouldn't have been reassigned to a string literal.


In general: if the variable is a pointer then = and == assigns/compares pointers, not the pointed-at data. Which is why such operations are wrong if we look to copy/compared the actual data.
Overall I always recommend to first learn arrays, then pointers, then strings, in that order. If you don't have a sound understanding of arrays and pointers, you won't understand C strings either. String handling in C is much more cumbersome than in other languages, since it deals with raw data rather than some convenient string class.
I wrote a little FAQ about the most common beginner bugs here: Common string handling pitfalls in C programming. You'll find some of the bugs from your code in that FAQ.

char *str1 = "HelloWorld";


"HelloWorld" is string literal and its lifetime is the same as the program. The string literal cant be modified.
str1 is pointer and it holds the reference to string literal

char str2[] = "HelloWorld";


str2 is char array having strlen("HelloWorld") + 1 elements. The string literal is being copied to this array. This array can be modified.

char *str3 = malloc(11 * sizeof(char));


str3 is a pointer to char holding the reference to memory allocated using the malloc function. The memory allocated has lifetime until it is freed by the free function or program termination.


str1, str2 and str3 are local to main function.
Arrays and pointers are not the same!! Pointers hold the address of the object. Arrays are continuous memory chunks.

Arrays can decay to pointers when used in expressions.
Arrays cant be assigned (except the initialization)

When you assign the pointer you do not copy the string (more generally the object) only assign the new address (reference) to the pointer
To compare strings you can't use == operator and = will not copy them. You need to use string functions like strcmp and strcpy for it
